# how to make a "secure" form with attachment that goes directly to email?

Tags: php, email, forms, captcha, attachment

question explains all, I managed to do the basic form info to email part but I'm confused when it comes to security and uploads. I'm not looking for a direct answer on how to program it but rather links explaining how this can be made and how to avoid having a badly programed form with no security and bugs and some demos (ps: my php skills are really low.)

Comment: Questions usually have a `?` in them...

Comment: What do you mean by “‘secure’”?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by what you said in your question that you are able to attach and e-mail the file but your concern is someone attaching the wrong type of file or too large of a file size.

I took the following from: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/file_upload.php

```
<?php
//Сheck that we have a file
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
  //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
  $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
  if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && 
    ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 350000)) {
    //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
      //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
      if (!file_exists($newname)) {
        //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
           echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
        } else {
           echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
        }
      } else {
         echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]." already exists";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload";
  }
} else {
 echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
?>
```

This checks the file type and the file size before uploading. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Is it possible to send an attachment without having it go on a tmp folder before going to the email? I've seen something similar before but I didn't understand how the person did it so I'm not sure

Comment: No, it must go in the tmp folder, this is a server setting. HOWEVER, you don't have to move it before attaching it to an email: you can read the contents of the file, attach said contents in the email, and then delete the file off the server.

Comment: Not possible with PHP upload. PHP streams the file uploads directly to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

A few very basic security precautions:

) NEVER trust contents of variables sent by the user. EVERY piece of data must be examined and processed.

) NEVER let the user, without very good reason, choose the name under which the file gets stored on the server.

) NEVER assume the filetype is what the extension says it is.

A quick google search brings up pages with decent information about what to watch out for. One example: http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat.htm